# Java output with currency formating, percentages, and half_up rounding

Tags: java, string, formatting, string-formatting

JAVA OUTPUT Question, please help.

How to format two outputs, first is to have an ouput using HALF_UP rounding and currency formating and the second is to have an ouput with precentage?

Supporting docs:

(A) orginal assignment

Introduction to Object-Oriented Programming

Programming Assignment – Discount Coupon

A supermarket awards coupons depending on how much a customer spends on groceries. For example, if you spend $50, you will get a coupon worth eight percent of that amount. The following table shows the percent used to calculate the coupon awarded for different amounts spent. Write a program that calculates and prints the value of the coupon a person can receive based on groceries purchased and the amount paid after the discount is applied.

Money Spent

Coupon Percent

Less than $10

No coupon

Between $10 and $60

8%

Between $61 and $150

10%

Between $151 and $210

12%

More than $210

14%

Note, as specified, it is not clear how to handle boundary conditions. For example, what is the coupon percent for $150.25? You should decide how you are going to handle boundary conditions and be sure to explain your choice in the program documentation.

Your program should use a currency instance for formatting dollar amounts and a percent instance for formatting percents. They can both be found in the java.text.NumberFormat package. Use the HALF_UP rounding mode for your currency displays.

Here is a sample run:
run:
Please enter the cost of your grocies: 78.24
You earned a discount of $7.82. (10% of your purchase)
Please pay $70.42. Thank you for shopping with us!

(B) code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Coupon {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();


        //Variables 
        double amountSpent=0;
        double couponAmount = 0;
        double totalAfterCoupon= 0; 
        final double lessThanTen = 0.00;
        final double betweenTenAndSixity = 0.08;
        final double betweenSixtyOneAndOneHundredAndFifty = 0.10;
        final double betweenOneHundredAndFiftyOneAndTwoHundredAndTen = 0.12;
        final double overTwoHundredAndTen = 0.14;



        System.out.print("Please enter the cost of your groceries: ");
        amountSpent = input.nextDouble();

        if (amountSpent<10 && amountSpent>=0)
        {
            couponAmount = lessThanTen * amountSpent;
            System.out.printf("You earned a discount of ", currency.format(couponAmount), "(0% of your purchase)");
        }
        else if (amountSpent>=10 && amountSpent<=60.49)
        {
            couponAmount = betweenTenAndSixity * amountSpent;
            System.out.printf("You earned a discount of ", currency.format(couponAmount), "(10% of your purchase)");
        }
        else if (amountSpent>=60.50 && amountSpent<=150.49)
        {
            couponAmount = betweenSixtyOneAndOneHundredAndFifty * amountSpent;
        }
        else if (amountSpent>=150.50 && amountSpent<=210)
        {
            couponAmount =  betweenOneHundredAndFiftyOneAndTwoHundredAndTen* amountSpent;
        }
        else if (amountSpent>210) 
          {
            couponAmount =  overTwoHundredAndTen* amountSpent;
          }
        else 
        {
        System.out.println("Please enter your total bill between $0.00 or greater. ");
        }

        System.out.printf("the coupon amount is: %f ", couponAmount);        
    }

}
```

Comment: This is probably not going to be well received. You need a much more specific question/problem. Surely your entire homework assignment and code are not relevant to the problem so you should narrow it down to only the information we need to see the problem you're encountering. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: You're right @tnw wouldn't say it better. But everyone of use had our first downvoted question right? I guess it's part of the initiation in SO! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

***Note:*** I notice you're a newcomer and I'm gonna give you this one for free (We've all need to learn things first), but please keep in mind that ther are certain rules in SO; Asking for homework corrections or bad research related questions aren't appreciated, specially if they both apply. Also as tnw mentioned you should narrow your question down to the specific part of code that's relevant, so that it can easily be reproduced or/and found by others that have the same issue.

In case of the answer to your formatting problem you have some amazing resources at Oracle's official docs, learn how to use their docs and you'll get the hang of Java in no time. On the `NumberFormat` class they have this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html , and you will also need the info on locale's in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html .

What you need to do to use the `NumberFormat` class is create an instance of the locale you're going to use like: `Locale enUSLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").setRegion("US").build();`
There are multiple other ways to do this.

And then use this locale to indicate the `NumberFormat` class what to use:

```
//Instantiate the NumberFormat:
NumberFormat USFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(enUSLocale);

//And print it:
System.out.println("You earned a discount of " + USFormat.format(couponAmount));
```

Well I hope this gives you the basis you need to go on and learn to use the docs and other info online!

Goo(gle)d Luck!